# htaccess to hide only files in php that I choose

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have the following code in my htacess file, that is working and “cleans” all .php extensions from my files. How can I modify my code in order to hide only the .php files that I will choose? For example to hide only .php extension from the "test.php" and the "test1.php" files.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]



RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Can't really test, but something like `RewriteRule ^(test|test1) %1 [R=302,L]` and `RewriteRule ^(.*?(test|test1))/?$ $1.php [L]` I think. Also I am curious if your current implementation would be vulnerable to a malicious (cross-domain) redirect via `https://example.com//sub.example.com/malicious/link.php`

Comment: works for test and test1, but now other files like test2 cannot load and not showing

Comment: Well, those do need the .php extension in that case.

Comment: Why would anyone want to hide `.php` extensions for few selected files only?